# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list' BUT the code works in my Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python

I am working on a project that compares the values in two different dictionaries (available and recipe) to find out the number of possible things that can be made out of the available ingredients.

My code has no problem running on my Jupyter Notebook but it returns the error below when run through codewars.

```
python

recipe = {"flour": 500, "sugar": 200, "eggs": 1}
available = {"flour": 1200, "sugar": 1200, "eggs": 5, "milk": 200}

total=[]
for x in recipe.keys() & available.keys():
    if (available[x] // recipe[x]) >= 0:
        total.append((available[x] // recipe[x]))

ltotal=sorted(total)
```

The expected outcome is the integer 2 but instead i am met with 
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'"

Comment: CodeWars must be using Python 2, try `set(recipe) & set(available)`

Comment: In python2, `.keys()` and `.values()` return lists, while in python3 they return special objects with more operators. `&` is a set operator, so you need to use `set(recipe.keys())` to convert the list of keys into a set.

Comment: I did not even see that the kata was using 2.76 and not 3+.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Codewars uses Python 2, where `dict.keys()` returns a list (lists don't support the `&` operation), but your notebook uses Python 3, where it returns a special `dict_keys` object (which does support said operation).

So, on Codewars you should convert `dict.keys()` to a set, which, like `dict_keys` in Python 3, supports the `&` operation.